# GitModules with different branches per repo branch

Tags: git

I have a Repo A. That has branches master and staging.
Repo B is a submodule that will have Branches master and staging as well.

I want Repo A master to point to Repo B master, and Repo A staging to point to Repo B staging.

Unfortunately .gitmodules file has a conflict, and do to CI/CD build and release pipelines, it would need to have the .gitmodules file in the project.

Right now the .gitmodules file,

```
 [submodule "REPOB"]
    path = path
    url = url
<<<<<<< HEAD
    branch = staging
=======
    branch = master
>>>>>>> master
```

and submodules folder have incosistencies.

```
-Subproject commit a7003f003b196ce1d5677779a7c9cb1447516c79
+Subproject commit 4b237d06f04d383e28f1582e320d1bc5e2637800
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no *requirement* that the `branch =` setting even *appear* in the `.gitmodules` file, much less that it contain the name that you want.  The setting is purely for your convenience.  If you find it inconvenient to have it set one way, or at all, set it some other way, or unset it.

The specific commit that each submodule should extract is stored as a *gitlink* entry inside the `tree` object for each commit.  So if the latest commit on `staging` has a `tree` that says that submodule REPOB should be on `a7003f003b196ce1d5677779a7c9cb1447516c79`, and your CI/CD process—or I should say, whatever software is running that—has that commit checked out and then runs `git submodule update`, Git will check out commit `a7003f003b196ce1d5677779a7c9cb1447516c79` in that submodule.  If the latest commit on `master` has a `tree` that says submodule REPOB should be on `4b237d06f04d383e28f1582e320d1bc5e2637800`, when your CI/CD process runs `git submodule update`, Git will check out commit `4b237d06f04d383e28f1582e320d1bc5e2637800` in that submodule.

When you go to make a new commit *for* `master` or *for* `staging`, be sure that the index you are using to *make* that new commit has, as its gitlink entry for submodule REPOB, whatever commit hash ID you want your CI/CD process to get when it runs `git submodule update`.  That's where the `branch = ...` convenience setting comes in: it might be convenient to have the correct name.  But it might be inconvenient by causing merge conflicts.  Pick whichever convenience you find the most convenient; Git won't give you both at the same time.

If your CI/CD software makes new commits on its own, figure out how *it* controls what's in *its* Git repository's index when it makes commits.  It (your CI/CD software) will need to make sure that its Git repo's index has the correct hash ID.  That may dictate which convenience is the most convenient.